# Infinite loop when running an activity

Tags: java, android, tabs, android-activity

I have this class:

```
public class Map extends ActionBarActivity implements TabListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_the_map);

     // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab ttestTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("The test");
        ActionBar.Tab chatTab = actionBar.newTab().setText("Chat");

        testTab.setTabListener(this);
        chatTab.setTabListener(this);

        actionBar.addTab(testTab, false);
        actionBar.addTab(chatTab, true);

        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        LatLng mapCenter = new LatLng(41.889, -87.622);
        LatLng mapCenter2 = new LatLng(41.889, -85.622);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.orienteering))
        .position(mapCenter)
        .flat(true)
);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.orienteering))
        .position(mapCenter2)
        .flat(true)
);

//        CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder()
//                .target(mapCenter)
//                .zoom(13)
//                .bearing(90)
//                .build();

//        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
//                new LatLng(-18.142, 178.431), 2));

        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

     // Animate the change in camera view over 2 seconds
//        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition),
//                2000, null);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater actionMenue = getMenuInflater();
        actionMenue.inflate(R.menu.the_map, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.goBack) {
            this.finish();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_the_map,
                    container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        int position = tab.getPosition();
        switch(position){
            case 0:
//              Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(this, Map.class);
//              startActivity(displayTheMap);
//              this.finish();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "case 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               break;

            case 1:             
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "case 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(this, Map.class);
                startActivity(displayTheMap);
                this.finish();

               break;
        }       
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

As you can see I have flagged the `chatTab` as selected and I have 2 cases in `onTabSelected` both of the cases are showing a toast with a message witch case is selected.

Now I'm calling the above `Map` class inside of my MainActivity by:

```
Intent displayTheMap = new Intent(this, Map.class);
            startActivity(displayTheMap);
```

and the emulator is showing the toast message `case 1` over and over again.

Why is this happening? Why it is looping trough case 1 over and over again? Isn't `case 0` already marked as selected? I know that I;m missing a really small part here, but I can't spot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In activity Map, you are adding a tab and making it selected (`actionBar.addTab(chatTab, true`);
2. You have a TabListener that starts the Map activity again when the tab is selected (`startActivity(displayTheMap);`)

You are correct, this is an infinite loop.

If you want the tab at position 0 to be initially selected, then swap your second parameters:

```
actionBar.addTab(testTab, true);
actionBar.addTab(chatTab, false);
```

Comment: Ok, but I need `chatTab` to be marked as selected/active tab

Comment: Then you can't restart the activity every time that tab is selected.

Comment: In Map.class, you are using startActivity with an Intent for Map.class. Why would you start the same activity you currently have open?

Comment: Lol, it took me 3 days to realize that I still have this in my code! It's lame. Thanks for the help!!!